# Create Map from two lists with some filtering

Tags: java, java-stream

I got two Lists as follows

```java
List<String> keys = List.of("A1", "B1", "A2", "B2");
List<List<String>> values = List.of(List.of("A1", "B1"), List.of("A2", "B2"), List.of("A1", "B2"), List.of("A2", "B1"));
```

And I wanted to make a Map from those two Lists *at the declaration time*.

```java
Map<String, List<List<String>>> result = Map.ofEntries(
    Map.entry("A1", List.of(List.of("A1", "B1"), List.of("A1", "B2"))),
    Map.entry("A2", List.of(List.of("A2", "B2"), List.of("A2", "B1"))),
    Map.entry("B1", List.of(List.of("A1", "B1"), List.of("A2", "B1"))),
    Map.entry("B2", List.of(List.of("A2", "B2"), List.of("A1", "B2")))
)
```

As you can see, each `map entry`'s value gathers `values entry` containing the key's value.

I tried to make this Map object using `stream` api, `map method` and `filter method`.

```java
Map<Object, Object> result1 = keys.stream()
    .map(key -> List.of(key, values.stream().filter(value -> value.contains(key)).toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(data -> data.get(0), data -> data.get(1)));
```

This worked but seems ugly.

I thought there should be an efficient way more than this one.

Show me the best way to improve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First stream the keys, and use the [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) collector. You specify what the keys and values of the map are, in terms of an element in the `keys` list.

The keys of the map are just the elements of the keys list, unchanged, and that the values of the map are the (inner) lists of `values` that contains the element in the `keys` list. This is where you can stream the `values` list and `filter`.

```
var result = keys.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    key -> key, // or Function.identity()
    key -> values.stream().filter(value -> value.contains(key)).toList()
));
```